# Argument 1 passed to Twig\Environment::getTemplateClass() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: php, twig

Been looking around but can't find anything to sort the issue.
I made a custom PHP MVC (using help from various sources), use Twig's template engine and rendering works fine. I added an custom Error handler which works as well.
I set a constant to show errors in dev but in prod just log them and render custom 404 and 500 views. When the twig render($template) function is called for this specific option it just returns the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Twig\Environment::getTemplateClass() must be of the type string, null given, called in
C:\Users\duboi\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\www\fabrice\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php on line 321 and defined in
C:\Users\duboi\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\www\fabrice\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php on line 259
```

There is no issue whatsoever when 404 and 500 http requests are not triggered. (existing routes/controllers/actions)
I looked through Twig's classes from the error listed and noticed the argument causing issue is $name from `public function \Twig\Environment::getTemplateClass($name, int $index = null): string`
I traced the functions calls and did a var_dump() in each one of them on the variable that ends up being the $name argument. All show `\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php:279:string '404.html' (length=8)` which is a String and is NOT NULL. Why does the error say it is?

Error.php:

```
public static function exceptionHandler($exception) {
    $code = $exception->getCode();
    if ($code != 404) {
        $code = 500;
    }
        
    http_response_code($code);
        
    if (\App\Config::SHOW_ERRORS) {
  [....]
    } else {
        $log = ROOT . DS . 'logs' . DS . date('Y-m-d') . '.txt';
        ini_set('error_log', $log);
        
        $message = "Uncaught Exception: '" . get_class($exception) . "'";
        $message .= " with message '" . $exception->getMessage() . "'";
        $message .= "\nStack trace: " . $exception->getTraceAsString();
        $message .= "\nThrown in '" . $exception->getFile() . "' on line " . $exception->getLine();
        
        error_log($message);
        View::renderTemplate($code . '.html');
    }
}
```

View.php:

```
public static function renderTemplate($template, $args = []) {
    static $twig = null;
    
    if ($twig === null) {
        $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(ROOT . DS . 'App' . DS . 'Views');
        $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    }
    echo $twig->render($template, $args); // this is the point of my code when the error occurs
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same error message. For me, the problem was, That I forgot to put the `baseTemplate` in quotes, Which I was extending in the template that I wanted to render.

( I had `{% extends firstTwigBaseTemplate.html %}`
instead of
`{% extends "firstTwigBaseTemplate.html" %})` )

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too...it's always the simplest things.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message. The fix for me was to empty the cache folder that Twig was using. After that, everything worked correctly.

More information about the compilation cache in the official document: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#compilation-cache